# Android : Is possible to add calendar event without calling the Google Calendar API or Starting Native Calendar activity?

Tags: android, calendar

I would like to ask, that is possible to add calendar event without calling the Google Calendar API (need internet connection) or Starting Native Calendar activity (is unnecessary)? Just add calendar event into device native calendar (no reading, filtering, etc..)

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [*CalendarProvider*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html). (See also [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html))

You can use it to read, write, update, and delete calendar events. Although you will need the calendar permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

You can then just use the users calendar or create your own.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to start native calender activity .

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,     Events.CONTENT_URI);
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance().set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance().set(2012, 0, 19, 10, 30);
```

calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
  calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
    calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Ninja class");
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Secret dojo");

Now start above activity. Hope it helps.

Comment: But Your example starts default calendar app(activity) with prefilled values.